# JSF f:ajax tag inside Jquery datepicker onselect event

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

How can I trigger `f:ajax` event upon jquery datepicker `onselect` event

Is it possible?

If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. The `f:ajax` functionality is added on the server side to a jsf component. The jQuery datepicker works on the client side.

Use the jQuery ajax functions instead, or one of the JSF based component libraries like Primefaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute `<f:ajax` on `onSelect` event you need a **workaround** cause `<f:ajax/>` is a JSF tag and cannot be conncted to jquery components the same way it does with JSF ones...,

just place

```
<h:commandButton id="myButton" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="..." listener="..." execute="..."/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and click on it from `onSelect` event like this

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("#myButton").click(); //this will click the hidden button and execute its `<f:ajax `
}
```

you might be needing a better selector for $("#myButton") (if its inside form without prependId="false" etc... but  guess it wont be a big deal for you...)

B.T.W

[primefaces library already integrated datepicker , the call it p:calendar , so take a look...](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarAjax.jsf)

Comment: you always save me.... so sweet...

Comment: I tried your way, but dates are going as null. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838329/for-ajax-datepicker-send-date-as-null)

Comment: @FahimParkar , If you want to send the updated the value to the server and not the initial one you have to use `execute="someId"` on that particular field

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. the problem was Hide variable was having `disabled=true` because of which data was going as null. in render I passed normal variable and then it worked fine...